# read parameter from a url

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to read a parameter from the URL, i am able to read for single line but i don't know how to loop in awk, can someone help?

i have file with 1000+ entries like

```
http://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_details.cfm?aid=7714687&icde=0
http://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_description.cfm?aid=7896503&icde=0
http://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_details.cfm?aid=7895320&icde=0
http://projectreporter.nih.gov/project_info_details.cfm?aid=2675186&icde=9195637
```

i am trying to only retrive "aid=xxxxxxx", i used the following command to do it and i get the "aid" for the last line

```
awk '{match($0,"aid=([^ &]+)",a)}END{print a[1]}' file1.txt > outputFile.txt
```

how to do the same in a loop so i can get all the occurrence? 
any help would be appreciated

Comment: With GNU `grep`, you may use `grep -oP 'aid=\K[^&]+' file1.txt`. Or, with `sed`: `sed -n 's/.*?aid=\([^&]*\).*/\1/p' file1.txt`

Comment: Seems like you just need to remove `END`.  That is, put the `print` statement in the same block as the `match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work a little fine tuning for your attempted code.

```
awk 'match($0,/aid[^&]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

---

---

In case your single line can have multiple occurrences of `aid` and you want to print all then try following.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/aid[^&]*/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```